# What algorithms can be used in Image Processing to detect the font drawn in the picture?

Tags: android, image-processing

What is the algorithm used for image processing in font making in android?
What language can I use in my font maker android application?

Answer (score -1):

You need to be more specific with your question. Read about Optical character recognition (OCR) algorithms for extracting letters from image. If you want to detect font type you need to apply some classification method. I recommend to read about Machine Learning with focus on classification.